# Use Jquery/Ajax to produce a WORKING HTML <a href> object

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I'm using an ajax request to a .php page to populate a section on my website dynamically.  None of the  objects in that section are clickable, although they are highlighted and underlined.

Here's what I tried: I'm sort of familiar with using Ajax and dynamically binding classes to event handlers.  So I've tried to bind every single class in the news posts section, in the success part of my AJAX request.  It simply does not work- it doesn't even pop up alerts.  The EXACT SAME CODE works on other parts of the page. Literally, the exact same code works on other parts of the page that are dynamically loaded.

Here's what should work

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../NewsDisplay.php",
        success: function(data){
        $(".displaynewsposts").html(data);
        $(document).on("click", ".displaynewsposts",function(){
        window.alert ("javascript is bugged");
        });
        }
    })
```

So that doesn't work.  I've tried every class on the page that loads in the news portion, and none of them work.  However, classes in other parts of the page that are dynamically loaded DO work.  I've tried every mouse action.  It literally makes no sense.  If you'd like to see JS fail in person, my test page on my website is www.progressfestival.com/index2.php

Also, there are no errors on the page.

Comment: you populate `.displaynewsposts` and then assign a `click` handler to the container? shouldn't you be assigning the `click` to contents within that container?

Comment: so I tried ".displaynewsposts" and ".newslinks" and ".newsformattop" ... just to get a reaction from JQuery... and Jquery does not react...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are delegating to items that are loaded by AJAX, try delegating prior to the success function:

```
var $displayNewsPosts = $('.displaynewsposts');

$displayNewsPosts.on('click','.newslinks',function(){
    alert('javascript is bugged');
});

$.ajax({
    url:'../NewsDisplay.php'
}).success(function(data){
    $displayNewsPosts.html(data);
});
```

This way the delegation is handled on page load, but should still operate at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.  Unfortunately, 2 hours later, I realized that JQuery WAS working, even in the success function - I had the container element blocking the anchor objects.

So for everyone with this problem in the future, make sure no other divs are secretly blocking your elements.  If you use Jquery.html(data) with Ajax, it should load the anchor elements without an issue!